# JavaFx : Is it possible to align the Box above the Text content in a checkbox?

Tags: java, css, javafx, fxml

I want to achieve somthing like this :

[image]

Comment: not supported (afaics, not entirely certain, though) - if really not: should be doable with a custom skin: implement its layoutChildren to do whatever you need

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below is one simple example of achieving what you want. The more professional way would be to implement a custom skin. Maybe someone else will share it.

**App:**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.text.TextAlignment;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        // Create a separated label at first:
        Label label = new Label("Am efectuat toate");

        // Create a check box without a text
        CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();

        // Put the check box as the graphic node of the label:
        label.setGraphic(checkBox);

        // Put the box on top of the label:
        label.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TOP);

        // Toggle selected property of checkbox on label primary mouse button click:
        label.setOnMouseClicked(mouseEvent -> {
            if (mouseEvent.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY)
                checkBox.setSelected(!checkBox.isSelected());
        });

        // If you want to have the last word "toate" in a second line:
        label.setWrapText(true);
        label.setMaxWidth(80);
        label.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);

        // Create scene and show:
        Pane root = new Pane();
        root.getChildren().add(label);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 120, 60));
        stage.show();
    }
    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

**Preview:**

[image: preview]